# Можете расставить запятые, где нужно?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

1. А что?
2. Жизнь такая нужно каждый раз терять дорогого тебе человека.
3. Видимо нет.
4. Что мне ещё сделать?
5. Ок делай что хочешь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**А что?

Жизнь такая, нужно каждый раз терять дорогого тебе человека.

Видимо, нет.

Что мне ещё сделать?

Ок, делай что хочешь.**